# nginx not use custom error page in one location

Tags: nginx

On the nginx server there are error pages configured to be used when eg. http status 404 gets returned. But I need to run a RestController witch returns dtos. In case of exceptions the http status might be 404. So in this case my dto with information in it gets thrown away by nginx and the custom error page gets shown to the user.
Is it possible to disable this behavior for explicit locations the nginx server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, for your location just set your custom error pages again but leave them out which you want not handled by nginx.